# React-pdf rendering affecting the whole UI Thread

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, web-worker, react-pdf

I'm using [react-pdf](https://react-pdf.org/) to render a pdf. The rendered pdf will change as I type on an input field.

The process goes like this...
First, when the input field changes, it triggers `setBlobData`

```
setBlobData: async (template) => {
    try {
        let blobData = await pdf(template).toBlob()
        store.setState({ pdfBlob: blobData });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then the `<Document></Document>` re-renders,

*Btw, I've set a `timeOut` of `.5ms` on input field change so that It will wait `.5ms` of inactivity before triggering `setBlobData`.* ***Note** that setting the Interval to atleast `1 second` is too long for the changes to reflect, that's why I set it to `.5ms`*

My conclusion is that, whenever the `<Document>` re-renders, it blocks the whole UI Thread.
thus, input field typing is not smooth.
So what I need is to maybe separate the `<Document>` component into a wrapper that runs on background/separate thread? I've read about `Web Workers` but I'm not too sure how to use it.

Any idea how I resolve this issue?

**Edited: ** I also memoized the `<Document>`.

Comment: I've never created PDFs the way you're doing, but is it possible to make async calls to that library? This will save you from blocking the UI thread for some part of the time. Off-context, I came across this issue when going through the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdNJ3fydeao)

Answer (score 0):

from what i'm seeing in the package it is already supposed to use a webworker.
[see here](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/blob/main/src/pdf.worker.entry.js)

Comment: Hmm, I'm already using the same version. but no luck. therefore its not about the webworker?

Comment: I believe you are looking at the wrong `react-pdf` library. The renderer is this one: https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf